# How do I scrape the jobs available on this site?

Tags: python, web-scraping

i am experiencing challenge scraping job posts from this website. I have tried the below link but it responds 'None' for each parameter.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://ng.indeed.com/jobs?q=customer%20service&l&vjk=1c0193efff1ca105').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
jobs = soup.find_all('h2', class_='jobTitle')

for soup in jobs:
    
company_name = soup.find('span', class_='companyName')
    
salary = soup.find('div', class_='metadata salary-snippet-container')
    
#print(job, company_name, salary)
    
published_date = soup.find('span', class_='date')
    
location = soup.find('div', class_='companyLocation')

print(f'''
    Company Name: {company_name}
    salary: {salary}
    Published Date: {published_date}
    Location: {location}
    ''')
```

Even when I changed the soup to job. e.g.

```
for job in jobs:
    company_name = job.find('span', class_='companyName')
```

I still got 'None' for all the parameters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Comment: in `jobs` you have `<h2>`  but `companyName` is NOT inside `<h2>`. You should fine some parent of all elements -ie. `<div class="job_seen_beacon">` - and later search other elements in this div.

Comment: next time maybe first use `print()` to see what you really have in variables.

Answer (score 1):

You get `<h2 class="jobTitle">` in `jobs` and you search other elements inside `<h2> ... </h2>` but these elements are outside `<h2>`.

You have to get different element in `jobs` - ie. `<div class="job_seen_beacon">`

And I don't see `salary` on this page. Maybe salary is on another page or it needs to login.

You need also `.text` to get only text from tag.

**EDIT:**

If you add to url `&start=0`, `&start=10`, etc. then you can get data from next pages.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://ng.indeed.com/jobs'

payload = {
    'q': 'customer service',
    'start': 0,
}

all_rows = []

for start in range(0, 70, 10):

    print('\n--- start:', start, '---\n')
    
    payload['start'] = start
    response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
    #print(response.status_code)
    
    html_text = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

    jobs = soup.find_all('div', class_='job_seen_beacon')

    for soup in jobs:
        
        company_name = soup.find('span', class_='companyName').text.strip()
            
        salary = soup.find('div', class_='metadata salary-snippet-container')
        if salary:
            salary = salary.text.strip()  
            
        published_date = soup.find('span', class_='date').text.strip()
            
        location = soup.find('div', class_='companyLocation').text.strip()
        
        row = [ company_name, salary, published_date, location]
        all_rows.append(row)
        
        print(f'''Company Name: {company_name}
salary: {salary}
Published Date: {published_date}
Location: {location}
---''')
        
# --- after loop ---

# - csv -

import csv

with open('output_1.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    
    headers = ["Company Name", "Salary", "Published Date", "Location"]
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)  # `writerow` without char `s` - to write single row

    csv_writer.writerows(all_rows)  # `writerows` with char `s` - to write list of rows

# - pandas -

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows, columns=["Company Name", "Salary", "Published Date", "Location"])

df.to_csv('output_2.csv', index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

Result:

```
--- start: 0 ---

Company Name: Tek Experts
salary: None
Published Date: Posted1 day ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: Rapidfire Healthcare
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Nigeria
---
Company Name: Green Africa Airways Limited
salary: None
Published Date: Posted15 days ago
Location: Abuja
---
Company Name: UNITED PARCEL SERVICE
salary: None
Published Date: Posted1 day ago
Location: Abuja
---
Company Name: Afrovirtues
salary: None
Published Date: Posted6 days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: Revocube Technologies
salary: None
Published Date: Posted15 days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: WhoGoHost
salary: None
Published Date: PostedToday
Location: Abuja
---
Company Name: Blueprints Pathway Limited
salary: None
Published Date: Posted14 days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: Divine Children's Place International School
salary: None
Published Date: Posted6 days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: MTN Nigeria
salary: None
Published Date: Posted8 days ago
Location: Abuja
---
Company Name: Dutum Company Limited
salary: None
Published Date: Posted16 days ago
Location: Abuja
---
Company Name: Field Intelligence
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Abuja
---
Company Name: Mitsubishi Power Europe, Ltd
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Nigeria
---
Company Name: Sunej Global Ventures LTD
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: Capital Luxury
salary: None
Published Date: Posted3 days ago
Location: Abuja+1 location
---

--- start: 10 ---

Company Name: Rich-Oak
salary: None
Published Date: PostedJust posted
Location: Abuja
---
Company Name: UGOSAM TECHNOLOGIES LIMITED
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: tugrow1688 logistics
salary: None
Published Date: Posted23 days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: Bons Industries Limited
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: Informatica
salary: None
Published Date: Posted2 days ago
Location: Plateau
---
Company Name: Cummins Inc.
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Abuja
---
Company Name: Field Intelligence
salary: None
Published Date: PostedToday
Location: Abuja+4 locations
---
Company Name: Consulate General Lagos
salary: None
Published Date: Posted2 days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: CHOPLIFE REPUBLIC
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Edo
---
Company Name: The Shawn Business Empire
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: NATHANS LIMITED
salary: None
Published Date: Posted28 days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: Chelink Group
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Lekki+1 location
---
Company Name: Showgear Limited
salary: None
Published Date: PostedToday
Location: Abuja
---
Company Name: Oxfam Novib
salary: None
Published Date: Posted1 day ago
Location: Taraba+1 location
---
Company Name: RELIABLE STEEL AND PLASTIC IND. LTD
salary: None
Published Date: PostedJust posted
Location: Anambra
---

--- start: 20 ---

Company Name: AB Microfinance Bank Nigeria
salary: None
Published Date: PostedToday
Location: Ekiti
---
Company Name: Kevicomms Nigeria Limited
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Port Harcourt
---
Company Name: Grafton Recruitment Sp. z o.o.
salary: None
Published Date: Posted17 days ago
Location: Plateau
---
Company Name: DriveMe Fleet Services
salary: None
Published Date: Posted9 days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: Export and Sell Limited
salary: None
Published Date: Posted6 days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: Uncle Stan's Foods
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: Chibek Instruments Ltd
salary: ₦100,000 - ₦150,000 a month
Published Date: Posted17 days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: Foodie24 Lagos Restaurant
salary: None
Published Date: Posted27 days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: VIASTORE
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Enugu
---
Company Name: 12 Baskets Foods Limited
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: Edves Nigeria Limited
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Kwara
---
Company Name: Atare 9ja Foodie Limited
salary: None
Published Date: Posted23 days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: Gbadebo Olamerun Agency Limited
salary: None
Published Date: Posted12 days ago
Location: Abuja
---
Company Name: Roots Foods Limited
salary: None
Published Date: Posted6 days ago
Location: Lagos
---
Company Name: Crush Cafe Abuja
salary: None
Published Date: Posted30+ days ago
Location: Abuja
---
```

Comment: Salary is posted there, kindly check the page again. Though some jobs have got no salary attached to them. In such case, I want to indicate Null. How do I do that?

Comment: you can use `try/except` to catch error and set `None`. OR use `if/else` to check value before `.text.strip()` - I add this version in answer.

Comment: Waow, it worked. Thank you. Please, permit me to ask on last question on this subject. If I want the job to include the other pages, how do i do it? That is, I want to get like up to 7pages long.

Comment: if you mean `pagination` then visit few pages and compare urls - and you will see that url for second page has `&start=10`, url for third page has `&start=20`, etc. So if you put cxode in loop which will add different values `&start=` then you should get differnt pages. ie.`for number in range(0,101,10): url = base_url + "&start=" + str(number)`

Comment: or you can search button with `>` which moves to next page and use this link to load next page. And you could run it in loop `while True:` and exit loop if you can't find button with `>` (you can find it searching attribute `aria-label="Next"`)

Comment: I added first method (with `for number in range(0,101,10):`) to code in answer.

Comment: How do i save it as CSV?

Comment: you can use standard module `csv` or popular `pandas` with `DataFrame`

Comment: I added code which write in csv.

Comment: Thank you. Though I tried using the code line as inputted by @Furas, yet it shows me the error below.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CHIDIEBERE NNAMANI\PycharmProjects\Webscrapping\CustomerServiceJobs_Indeed.py", line 46, in <module>
    csv_writer.writerow(all_rows)
  File "C:\Users\CHIDIEBERE NNAMANI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20a6' in position 24: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: error shows it writes with encoding `CP1250` - and it has problem to write char with code `\u20a6`. When I run `print('\u20a6')` then you get `'₦'` - so it can be char which doesn't exists in encoding `CP1250` (popular endcoding in Windows). You may need to use `open(..., encoding='utf-8')` and `.to_csv(..., encoding='utf-8')` to write it as `UTF-8`. I add this to code.